# Создание базы картинок для дальнейшего использования

Tags: javascript, sql, база-данных

Есть задача, при заходе на сайт, выдавать случайную картинку из 300 возможных. Все картинки хранятся на компьютере. Появилась необходимость создать некую базу, в которой они и будут храниться, а дальше я уже буду их оттуда вытаскивать. Вопрос лишь в том, как и на чем такую базу создать.

Comment: Храните картинки на сервере. Если нужно создайте массив с путями до картинок.

Comment: Да не нужна эта база. Просканировать заданный каталог на предмет имён трёх сотен файлов-картинок в нём и запомнить это дело в массиве/коллекции - операция не сказать что длительная. Зато не надо будет париться с обновлением списка файлов в базе. Будь тех файлов миллион, из которых надо выбрать триста по шаблону имени - тогда да... Но если всё же хочется базы - из javascript вполне нормально юзается ADO.

Comment: сайт на апаче? если просто выводить случайную картинку то как написал Akina

Comment: "картинки хранятся на компьютере" - осталось выяснить у кого этот компьютер (клиент или сервер)?